# Random reputation loss and gain

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I have spent some time reading other (mostly closed as duplicate) questions on random reputation gain and loss. I have not found one that matches my case or answers my question and I just still don't get *it* so I wanted to ask my own question.
Earlier today, I have noticed a loss of -1 reputation. Not long, later I was given the 1 point back.

[image]

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490628/code-improvements-for-counting-the-pages-of-pdf-files/16669101#16669101)  
 [Code improvements for counting the pages of PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490628/code-improvements-for-counting-the-pages-of-pdf-files/16669101#16669101)

This question has been asked in January. It's not the type of question I would even look at, so most likely I have not even seen it nor done any voting, commenting, etc. on it.

So my question is : 
**How is my account associated with that question? Why did I randomly lost and then re-gained the reputation?**

Comment: You downvoted an answer and then that answer was removed, so you got your reputation back.

Comment: I know for sure I have not downvoted any answers in that thread

Comment: I guess only a developer can confirm or deny it. But that is what must have happened. Perhaps it was part of a review queue item you evaluated?

Comment: Well... *someone* downvoted the deleted answer, and the system sure seems to think it was you.

Comment: even if i downvoted an answer that would have been recorded somewhere in the votes tab on the profile page <- and i have checked and did not find anything

Comment: @mehow I think you can't see your votes on deleted posts there (at least before you have 10K).

Comment: If that post is subsequently deleted, your downvote will not show up in the votes tab.

Comment: You guys are all right! ive located a trace now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you downvoted that answer you posted, which incurred a -1. That answer was then deleted, which caused you to get your 1 reputation back.

Comment: Oh, ok I can't say I did not downvote an answer. I actually did - so I apologize to the lads who have pointed it out in the first place. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hWzWY.png)